# Cognito Forms Notifications

Tags: cognito-forms

I have made a rather complex form using Cognito forms.

Basically, I want to setup a notification to send when a field is updated after submission using the edit shared entry link.

For example, say I have 2 fields "Name" and "Phone Number". A user has submitted their Name as John Smith and their Number as 9999999.

Later, the user opens the edit link and changes their Number to 888888 and resubmits the form.

Is there a way to setup a notification or notifications to email me only the fields that have been updated? So your notification would have a subject of "Phone Number" has been updated?

Answer (score 0):

Not easily, if at all. You'd be looking at an email with a ton of logic and in the end you'd probably still be looking at the same data. A better option might be to have the data exported to something like a SharePoint list and compare entries with duplicate names.

Answer (score -1):

You could make the field be read only after it was submitted:

```
Entry.DateSubmitted != null
```